# How to detect the return type in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a an event handler `(event:ResultEvent)` that could return 1 of 2 types. Does actionscript3 have a function to test the type returned? something like

```
if (type(event.result) == ProxyObject) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
if (event.result is ProxyObject) {}
```

More details are [here](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000045.html).